# MS Reportserver shows Login when I request a Report over URL - how I can avoid this?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, web-applications, reportserver

I use MS ReportServer in my ASP.NET Web-Application. The reports are requested over URL.

But when my application is trying to request a report, a little modal is showing and ask me for username and password.

How I can avoid this? I cannot build an application where the users must put in my login credentials to the ReportServer.

Hope someone can help.

[image]

Comment: You need to configure the authentication method of your ReportServer.

Comment: How can I do it? Every Visitor of my Website should be able to se the report. How I can configure it?